# Forward and Backward functionality not works for long video in Video tag of html 5

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming, html5-video, video-processing

I am using Html video tag. I have added video **URL from azure blob**. When I click on play then it starts playing but when I want to make forward and backward to video, it is not going on that position where I want to start play. It is still on that current position. So I want to show loading when I click on forward when video is not ready to play same as YouTube. Here is my code:

```
<video id="video" class="family-post-img" controls="controls"
   <source src="@Model.FileURL" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I want to show video buffering as YouTube when I directly click on forward and backward if video is not ready to play.

Thanks

Comment: did you find the solution of this ? Actually I am also stack to forward/rewind the large videos in html. It works fine for small one but not the large one. Could you please help me out how you resolve your issue ?

Answer (score 1):

When a user seeks through a video two events fire...

1. **onseeking** triggers while they are seeking
2. **onseeked** triggers when they are finished seeking.

Therefore, you need to monitor these events and take appropriate action, like this...

```
 <video src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" onseeking="CallAction1();" onseeked="CallAction2();" controls></video>
```